# Setting data-* dynamically and obtaining it onclick Meteor

Tags: jquery, mongodb, meteor

I am using Meteor to create an website for Campus Recruitment.
Here I have a mongo collection containing a list of companies that are going to visit different colleges.
The HTML looks Like

```
[{#each jobs}}
                <li class="list-group-item college-list"><a>Visit scheduled for {{college}} on {{posted}} for the post of {{designation}}by {{companyname}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

The JavaScript code is

```
'click .college-list' : function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = {get That Attribute};
    console.log(data);
}
```

Now what i have to do is on click of any anchor tag i want to redirect to that particular Job Post.For that i want to associate the organizations name that has post this job.
I tried the data-*  attribute and set it as {{collegename}} but that didnt work.Please suggest a solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'click .college-list' : function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = this.companyname;
    console.log(data);
}
```

Using this.*field* you can access every field of this document as well.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!